# Convergence of a series by comparsion test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My book says, that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3 + (-1)^k}{k^2}$$
is convergent. I used comparsion test to determine it. $\frac{3 + (-1)^k}{k^2} \leq 3 + (-1)^k$, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3 + (-1)^k$ is divergent.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approximation misses the point: we need to keep the $\frac{1}{k^2}$ bit - we know that $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges, so it's helping us. What we need to do is sort out that mess on the top. In particular, we bound $$\dfrac{3 + (-1)^k}{k^2}\leq \dfrac{4}{k^2},$$ and hence the result.